# How do I subtract values from one column from another in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

I have a dataframe where the rows are the names of different genes, with 2 columns called: Control_mean and Patient_mean.

I want to create a third column where I store the value of "Patient_mean - Control_mean" for each row respectively but I cant figure out how!

I tried to do so using this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(newdf8)){
  newdf8$log2FC[i] <- (newdf8[,2] - newdf8[,1])
}
```

but it didnt work, since all the values in the new column became the same number, and not the value of the actual difference.

Comment: Perhaps `newdf8[i, 2] - newdf8[i, 1]`?

Comment: @Lina - fyi you don't need a for loop for that. The operation is vectorized so you can just do this `newdf8$log2FC = newdf8[,2] - newdf8[,1]`

Comment: Aha, I'll keep that in mind for the future thanks!

Comment: Ok so I ran into a new problem.. how would I delete all rows from this dataframe, where the value in column 3 is within a certain range?  
(in this case; -0.5849<= value <= 0.5849 )?  ^^

Comment: Idk what your col names are but you could do something like this. `df <- df[df$value >= -0.5849 & df$value <= 0.5849,]`

Comment: Oh, my bad if I was unclear, I meant I want to remove the rows with column3-values within that range, only keeping rows with values for col3 above 0.5849 or below -0.5849. Otherwise the code worked great lol.


I tried to use the same code but doing this:
df <- df[df$value >= 0.5849 & df$value <= -0.5849,]

but it didnt seem to work..

Comment: Okay in that case you should use or `|` instead of `&`. Because that logic won't work. You want `value` to be less than -.5 OR greater than .5.